# Creating LinkedList exits with return code -11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

So I'm trying to create a Linked List class to understand better how pointers and data structures work but I keep running into a -11 SIGSEGV error. When I looked up the error it said that I might be using dereferenced pointers or accessing an array out of its bounds but neither of those makes sense for my program. I've searched everywhere for similar issues but none of them seem to apply to my program. Can anyone else see what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#pragma once
using namespace std;

#define NODE typename LinkedList<T>::Node*

template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    void AddHead(const T& data); //Adds new node to the beginning of the list
    void AddTail(const T& data); //Adds new node to the end of the list
    LinkedList(); //Default constructor
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& list); //Copy constructor

    struct Node {
        /*Individual node that stores the data*/
        T data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
        Node(); //Default constructor for node
        Node(T _data); //Data constructor for node
        Node(T _data, Node* _prev, Node* _next); //Full constructor for node
    };
private:
    NODE head = nullptr;
    NODE tail = nullptr;
    unsigned int count;

};

/*Function definitions*/

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddHead(const T& data) {
    NODE tempRef = new Node(data, nullptr, head);
    head->prev = tempRef;
    head = tempRef;
    delete tempRef;
    count++;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddTail(const T& data) {
    NODE tempRef = new Node(data, tail, nullptr);
    tail->next = tempRef;
    tail = tempRef;
    delete tempRef;
    count++;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    count = 0;
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& list) {
    this->head = list.head;
    this->tail = list.tail;
    this->count = list.count;
}

/*Node Constructors*/

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node() {
    next = nullptr;
    prev = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T _data) {
    next = nullptr;
    prev = nullptr;
    data = _data;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T _data, Node* _prev, Node* _next) {
    next = _next;
    prev = _prev;
    data = _data;
}
```

Comment: This    head = tempRef;
    delete tempRef; does not make sense. After these statements head has an invalid value because the pointed object was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The both functions `AddHead` and `AddTail` have a serious bug because the allocated node is at once deleted

```
head = tempRef;
delete tempRef;
```

and

```
tail = tempRef;
delete tempRef;
```

So the pointers head and tail have invalid values.

Moreover the functions do not update `tail` and `head` correspondingly in each function.

And initially the both pointers are equal to `nullptr`. So these statements

```
head->prev = tempRef;
```

and

```
tail->next = tempRef;
```

result in undefined behavior.

The function `AddHead` can be defined the following way

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddHead(const T& data) {
    NODE tempRef = new Node(data, nullptr, head);

    if ( head == nullptr )
    {
        head = tail = tempRef;
    }
    else
    {
        head = head->prev = tempRef;
    }

    count++;
}
```

And the function `AddTail` can look like

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddTail(const T& data) {
    NODE tempRef = new Node(data, tail, nullptr);

    if ( tail == nullptr )
    {
        tail = head = tempRef;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = tail->next = tempRef;
    }

    count++;
}
```

The copy constructor (and the copy assignment operator) either should be defined as deleted or shall make a deep copy of the list passed as the argument.

Otherwise two lists will try to delete the same nodes two times (in the forgotten by you destructor).

The structure `Node` should be declared as a private class member.

Comment: Wouldn't not deleting tempRef cause a memory leak? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still pretty new to memory allocation

Comment: @ManuKolehmainen You have allocating memory at at once deleted it. So the pointers have invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

You `delete` the nodes you add to the list in both `AddTail` and `AddHead`. This leaves pointers to garbage in the list.

Also, it's not clear how to use your linked list. You cannot call `AddHead` if `head` is `nullptr` (because `AddHead` dereferences `head`) and you cannot call `AddTail` if `tail` is `nullptr`. Since your constructor sets both `head` and `tail` equal to `nullptr`, what can you do next?

If it's legal for `head` to be `nullptr`, why does `AddHead` do `head->prev = tempRef;` without checking if `head` is `nullptr`?

I would strongly urge you to document your code. For example, what are the required preconditions for `AddHead` to be called? Is it supposed to be safe to call if `head` is `nullptr` or is it a requirement that it not be? Why is that not documented?

Comment: I hadn't thought of head being equal to nullptr causing issues. Coming from Java I thought if it was nullptr I could later initialize it to whatever I needed, but apparently its not that easy in C++

Comment: You can initialize it later to whatever you want, you just can't dereference it before you initialize it.